# How to filter a nested array object data

Tags: javascript

I am having this array of object

```
 const myArrayData = [
    {
        "user": "564b6deec50de8d827c0a51a",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://link-to-image.com.iga",
                "size": 16
            },
            {
                "image": "https://3link-to-image.com.iga2",
                "size": 70
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "user": "564b7527ecc479e4259edff7",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://44link-to-image.com.iga",
                "size": 32
            },
            {
                "image": "https://13link-to-image.com.iga23",
                "size": 45
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "user": "564e0a18c8cd4b5420a9250c",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://84link-to-image.com.iga",
                "size": 120           
             },
            {
                "image": "https://93link-to-image.com.iga23",
                "size": 8
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

I want to filter out the images array object that has a size below 20

So I should get this response which filtered out the images array object that has a size **below 20**

```
[
    {
        "user": "564b6deec50de8d827c0a51a",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://3link-to-image.com.iga2",
                "size": 70
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "user": "564b7527ecc479e4259edff7",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://44link-to-image.com.iga",
                "size": 32
            },
            {
                "image": "https://13link-to-image.com.iga23",
                "size": 45
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "user": "564e0a18c8cd4b5420a9250c",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "https://84link-to-image.com.iga",
                "size": 120           
             }
        ],
    },
  ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Update

```
exports.getImages = async (req,res) => {
    const myArrayData = await ImageModel
    .find()
    .exec()
    if(!result) return res.status(400).json({ data: null });
    if(result.err) return res.json({ err: err });
  
    const newResult = myArrayData.map(data => {
      return {
          user: data.user,
          images: data.images.filter(item =>
            item.size >= 20
          ),
      }
    })
    
  res.json(newResult);
}
```

I tried getting the data from mongoose and apply the filter, but it returns empty images array, but when I use the static data it works fine

```
[
    {
        "user": "564b6deec50de8d827c0a51a",
        "images": []
    },
    {
        "user": "564b7527ecc479e4259edff7",
        "images": []
    },
    {
        "user": "564e0a18c8cd4b5420a9250c",
        "images": []
    }
]
```

..................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What do the dots represent?

Comment: @Solar Mike The dot is just used as a line, It's not part of the code

Comment: You could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: @tromgy Can you give a more detail example

Comment: If you `console.log(myArrayData)`, do you have images with size above 20? Can you show the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you should try this

```
const result = myArrayData.map(data => {
  return {
      user: data.user,
      images: data.images.filter(item =>
        item.size >= 20
      ),
  }
})
```

[code](https://playcode.io/1055903)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what if I want to have multiple conditions (e.g) item.size >= 20 and item.image == 'a particular string'

Comment: @Liam  `data.images.filter(item => item .size >= 20 && item.image === 'https://3link-to-image.com.iga2')`

Comment: @Juljo Shahini  Thank you, Can you please check my updated question, when getting the arrayData for mongoose db it returns empty images array as a response

Comment: @CodeOz  Can you please check my updated question, when getting the arrayData for mongoose db it returns empty images array as a response

Comment: @Liam `console.log(myArrayData)` see the contains of it, something must be different compared to your hardcoded response.

Comment: @Juljo Shahini Thanks so much,, something was different which is the Image model.